# rails 3 response format and versioning using vendor MIME type in the Accept header

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, versioning, respond-with

**Preamble:**

I investigated how to version an API and found several ways to do it.  I decided to try [peter williams'](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/) suggestion and created new vendor mime types to specify version and format.  I could find no definitive write-up for doing this following "the rails way" so I pieced together info from several places.  I was able to get it working, but there is some goofiness in the way the renderers handle Widget array vs Widget instance in `respond_with`.

**Basic steps & problem:**

I registered mime types and added renderers for version 1 in both xml and json to ApplicationController, the renderers call `to_myproj_v1_xml` and `to_myproj_v1_json` methods in the model.  `respond_with(@widget)` works fine but `respond_with(@widgets)` throws an `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` saying that the "Template is missing".

**Workaround:**

"Template is missing" means that no render was called and no matching template exists.  by accident, I discovered that it is looking for a class method... so I came up with the code below which works but I'm not really happy with it.  The goofiness is mostly in and related to `xml = obj.to_myproj_v1_xml(obj)` and the duplication in the model.

My question is - has anyone done anything similar in a slightly cleaner fashion?

**-= updated code =-**

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**:

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.com.mydomain.myproj-v1+xml', :myproj_v1_xml
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.com.mydomain.myproj-v1+json', :myproj_v1_json
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate

  ActionController.add_renderer :myproj_v1_xml do |obj, options|
    xml = obj.to_myproj_v1_xml
    self.content_type ||= Mime::Type.lookup('application/vnd.com.mydomain.myproj-v1+xml')
    self.response_body = xml
  end

  ActionController.add_renderer :myproj_v1_json do |obj, options|
    json = obj.to_myproj_v1_json
    self.content_type ||= Mime::Type.lookup('application/vnd.com.mydomain.myproj-v1+json')
    self.response_body  = json
  end
end
```

**app/models/widget.rb**:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  V1_FIELDS = [:version, :model, :description, :name, :id]

  def to_myproj_v1_xml
    self.to_xml(:only => V1_FIELDS)
  end

  def to_myproj_v1_json
    self.to_json(:only => V1_FIELDS)
  end

  def as_myproj_v1_json
    self.as_json(:only => V1_FIELDS)
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb**:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :myproj_v1_xml, :myproj_v1_json

  def index
    @widgets = @user.widgets
    respond_with(@widgets)
  end

  def create
    @widget = @user.widgets.create(params[:widget])
    respond_with(@widget)
  end

  def destroy
    @widget = @user.widgets.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@widget.destroy)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@widget = @user.widgets.find(params[:id]))
  end

...

end
```

**config/initializers/monkey_array.rb**

```
class Array

  def to_myproj_v1_json(options = {})
    a = []
    self.each { |obj| a.push obj.as_myproj_v1_json }
    a.to_json()
  end

  def to_myproj_v1_xml(options = {})
    a = []
    self.each { |obj| a.push obj.as_myproj_v1_json } # yes this is json instead of xml.  as_json returns a hash
    a.to_xml()
  end

end
```

**UPDATE:**

Found another solution that feels better but still a little weird (I'm still not completely comfortable with monkey patches), probably ok though... basically moved building the response data from the class method `to_myproj_v1_json` to a monkey patch on Array.  This way when there is an Array of Widgets, it calls the instance method `as_myproj_v1_json` on each Widget and returns the whole Array as desired format.

One note:

- as_json has nothing to do with json format, just creates a hash.  Add custom formatting to as_myproj_v1_json (or an as_json override if you aren't using custom mime types), then to_json will change a hash to a json string.

i have updated the code below to be what is currently used, so the original question may not make sense.  if anyone wants the original question and code shown as was and fixed code in a response i can do that instead.

Comment: You have a question? I don't understand...

Comment: I found it hard to find the question in this post, but I did eventually find it. However, if you have arrived at a solution on your own then please post as an answer rather (and mark as accepted) than updating the question.

Comment: @jay, I'd say you need to be more careful about editing your posts in the future - arriving at your question a visitor is now greeted with "UPDATE:  found another solution..." which is very confusing.

Comment: Edited to fix all the confusion.

Comment: I started on a gem to help fix problems like these: https://github.com/amaabca/mime_version Please let me know if you have tried it and any feedback you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer: see the question :-)

In short, there are different solutions, of which one is in the question above:

- Monkey-patch Array to implement a method that will give the (old) v1 JSON back

Comment: yeah, that was my SO n00bness coming out.  hopefully with the help of edits it is more clear...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this content type trick used anywhere in a Rails project before so this is new to me. The way I've typically seen it done is to define a route namespace (e.g. /api/v1/) which goes to a controller (say, Api::Version1Controller).

Also, I know you want to do things the "Rails way", and maybe this sounds crotchety coming from a guy who has been with Rails since 1.3, but the whole `respond_with` / `respond_to` stuff is rather magic to me. I didn't know that `respond_to` looks for a `to_XXX` method when it serializes objects, for instance (maybe I need to read up on that). Having to monkey-patch Array like that seems rather silly. Besides, for an API, formatting the model data is really the view's job, not the model's. I might look into something like [rabl](http://github.com/nesquena/rabl) in this case. There's a good writeup about it [here](http://engineering.gomiso.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: i looked at both using route namespace and content type when investigating this.  the content-type specifier seems more "RESTful" in that a resource is always defined with a single uri as /widget/1 instead of having 2 uri's /widget/1.json and /widget/1.xml.  i totally agree with the point that the view should be doing the representation, and rabl looks very interesting too, thanks for pointing that out!