# Rails 3 and JSON: Default renderer but custom mime type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rendering, mime-types

Using ROAR ( https://github.com/apotonick/roar ) and without using ActiveRecord or any view-templates I want to:

- use the **default** JSON rederer but my **own** mime type to render JSON with respond_with
- use the **default** JSON parser but my **own** mime type to put entries of the POST-body into the params hash.

config/initializers/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.xxx-v1+json" , :xxx_v1
```

controllers/api/base_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :xxx_v1

  ActionController.add_renderer :xxx_v1 do |obj, options|
    json = obj.to_json
    self.content_type ||= Mime::Type.lookup('application/vnd.xxx-v1+json')
    self.response_body  = json
  end
end
```

controllers/api/user_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController 

  def index
    respond_with User.all
  end
end
```

GET http://domain/users
Accept application/vnd.xxx-v1

ERROR: Missing template api/v1/users/index, api/v1/base/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:xxx_v1], :locale=>[:en, :en]}

After reading several posts like
[Rails Custom Renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284443/rails-custom-renderer) or [rails 3 response format and versioning using vendor MIME type in the Accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754012/rails-3-response-format-and-versioning-using-vendor-mime-type-in-the-accept-head) I still can't get it work..

-=== small update ===-

When I use render directly in the controller, it's working! Always problems with respond_with...

```
render :xxx_v1 => User.all
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for rendering:

Put an empty method into your models:

```
def to_xxx_v1
end
```

It is not called but has to be present for respond_with.

Answer (score 4):

For automatic parsing of http bodies with custom mime types do:
**config/initializers/mime_types.rb** :

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::DEFAULT_PARSERS[Mime::Type.lookup('application/vnd.xxx_v1+json')]=lambda do |body|
  JSON.parse(body)
end
```

Comment: This answers a different, although still interesting question, than posed above, i.e., this answers "how to I parse" while the question above asks "how to I render."

Comment: But my question also includes "use the default JSON parser but my own mime type" ;D